# Favorites system in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favorites

What is the best way to add to favorites in Rails 3?
I found only this article about favorites system but it was posted in 2009.

[User favorites system](http://doblock.com/articles/creating-an-extensible-user-favorites-system-in-rails)

Is it the best way to make such system or you can suggest something more?

Answer (score 0):

That link you pointed to will work fine.

The thing you have to remember though is that the "best" way will depend entirely on how you app is set up and what you want to accomplish with your favorites system. My suggestion is to read through the [Rails Guide for associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: My app has Posts, Users(Devise gem). I need to make favourite system so users can add to favorites any post. The problem is that post belongs to user and i think i should make favorites system like in link.

Answer (score -2):

In order to model this kind of system extensive planning is required and this is entirely your choice on how you implement it...I would suggest that you first have a good look at the ActiveRecord::Associations, Callbacks and Validations as they are the Money logic in any app...There are a number of good screencasts which are present on the Railscasts.com for FREE. A reading about them on the api guide of Rails would also be beneficial

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.